# Publishhtml not working for jenkins agent within kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

The publish html report does not work for my jenkins agent in kubernetes when jenkins is not running within kubernetes, however it works when jenkins is in kubernetes, this leads me to believe that this is a networking issue, does anyone know what ports I might need, or is this due to the something to do with the /var/lib/jenkins folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allowed inbound on all ports in kubernetes and this resolved it.